# Android JNI System.loadLibrary not needed?

Tags: java, c++, android, java-native-interface

I need your help to add some insight into JNI on Android.  I've been looking at the /libcore/x-net package in Android and notice that Apache Harmony is the default provider for SSL functionality (using OpenSSL).

Everywhere I've found on the internet says that when you use JNI in Android you must load the native code by using the System.loadLibrary(...) method, but I can't see where Apache Harmony uses this at all.  I am confused as to how their native code is ever loaded.  Nowhere in their Java code do they ever load their native library.

**/libcore/x-net/src/main/java/org...**   [Java Code of JNI]
**/libcore/x-net/src/main/native/...**    [C++ Code for JNI]

Chris

Comment: BTW, where have you seen this documented, that JNI works only to code loaded with System.loadLibrary()? (I.e. not to code loaded with dlopen() (said dlopen() then called from code that *is* loaded with System.loadLibrary()). It matches what I think I see, but I would just like to know if it's even intentional and documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrisc,

To follow up on adding a new provider, you can add the files anywhere you want, including within an application. Android already has multiple providers registered in different packages. For example, in dalvik/libcore/security/src/main/java/java/security/Security.java

```
// Register default providers
private static void registerDefaultProviders() {
    secprops.put("security.provider.1", "org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.DRLCertFactory");  //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
    secprops.put("security.provider.2", "org.apache.harmony.security.provider.crypto.CryptoProvider");  //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
    secprops.put("security.provider.3", "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.JSSEProvider");  //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
    secprops.put("security.provider.4", "org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider");  //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
}
```

and also redundantly in libcore/security/src/main/java/java/security/security.properties

However, even if you add your own classes into the same package, it won't affect the existing provider. That is because the Provider classes such as in this case JSSEProvider are what define what classes are used to provide various algorithm implementations (through the properties you see put above)

In your case, you probably want to provide a new SSLContext implementation. You can see in JSSEProvider that it registers SSLContextImpl to provide a "TLS" (aka SSL) implementation of SSLContext:
                 put("SSLContext.TLS", SSLContextImpl.class.getName());

So you could add your own Provider that register an alternative implementation.

You do not need to to add your Provider to Security.java or security.properties, but you can use Security.addProvider to add a new one, or even Security.insertProviderAt to control where your Provider will appear in priority order.

Once you have your own Provider registered, you can ensure you get an instance from your new Provider by using SSLContext.getInstance("SSLContext", "your-provider-name"). Alternatively if you provider is made higher priority than the built in one, all programs calling SSLContext.getInstance("SSLContext") will get your new implementation.

One other note is that SSLSocket's can also be created with SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(). That can be overriden to use your own SSLSocketFactory with ssl.SocketFactory.provider=org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl (looking at SSLSocketFactory.getDefault). I'm not sure that can be done within an application, unlike adding a new provider.

Finally, as far as the C++ code, you can obviously provide your own JNI native code. If you are just doing it in an app, you'd register it like any other JNI code (or have it autoloaded) but I don't have the details on that handy since I work with the built in code most of the time. As with most native code, you would need to avoid symbol name collisions if you are building your code into the VM like the current code. We try to make as much of the code staticly scoped to the file to avoid such issues. However, providing a different version of libssl.so itself is another matter entirely. If you need to do something like that, I don't have any tested device.

You might find this follow document useful as well for a background adding new providers:
How to Implement a Provider in the Java™ Cryptography Architecture
http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html

-bri

Answer (score 3):

```
% arm-eabi-objdump -p .../symbols/system/lib/libdvm.so
 ...
Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               libnativehelper.so

% cat dalvik/libnativehelper/Android.mk
 ...
static_libraries := \
    libjavacore \
    libfdlibm
```

It's pulled in automatically as part of the VM binary.  The native methods are registered explicitly -- see dalvik/libnativehelper/Register.c.

Loading the library dynamically would work for something like the SSL implementation, but is problematic for many of the core classes because the implementation is needed to do the shared library loading.

Comment: Thanks fadden!  I've been searching for that for a long time.  If you don't mind, can I get your opinion on my problem?  I'm tying to add a new provider for the javax.net.ssl package (currently it is org.apache.harmony.xnet.jsse).  This can be found under (/libcore/x-net/src/main).  Where should I put my java and C++ files as to not overwrite the existing provider and still have it build correctly?

Comment: Not sure, I'll ping somebody.

Comment: Ok, Thanks.  Just to state where I have placed them so far, I put my java package in "/libcore/x-net/src/main/java/myjavapackage" (alongside the package of the existing provider), and created a folder for my native code at "/libcore/x-net/src/native-cyassl".  The existing provider's native code is at "libcore/x-net/src/native".